# Can't connect to WiFi

Tags: wireless

I downloaded Ubuntu and now I can't connect to WiFi and that is why do something. I haven't got any permanent connection through LAN. My computer doesn't see anything and I don't know where to download drivers for WiFi for Ubuntu or what to do with system. Model of my laptop is Dell Inspiron 1470. Version of Ubuntu - 12.04. Pls, help me good people :)

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Answer (score 0):

First of all, two silly questions: is your computer's WiFi lamp on? Is your wireless network working OK?

If so, can you see the Network Manager icon at the upper right hand corner? If so, click on it and choose Edit. After choosing the right parameters, you may need to turn networking and wireless off and then on, using this same menu.

You can also check whether the Broadcom module is present:

lsmod | grep bcm

(However, if your install proceeded OK, this module should have been installed.)